# I would like to accept a question but is missing something, what should I do?

Tags: discusión

In this question [¿Cuál es la palabra más generalmente aceptada para decir "calzado deportivo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/cual-es-la-palabra-mas-generalmente-aceptada-para-decir-calzado-deportivo) I would like to accept the answer by Joze.

But I would like to edit it, so the actual answer has more relevance, where he says "calzado deportivo", and I would like it to mention too "zapatillas deportivas".
I feel that way his answer would be complete.

I don't know what is the best thing to do in this case. Should I edit his answer? Or should I ask him to edit it?

In the other hand he didn't suggest "zapatillas deportivas", but in my experience "zapatillas" is linked to this kind of shoe, and in the answer by Fran, he mentioned it.

I am not sure what would be the best way to act in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I say: edit it. If the OP hates it, he can roll back the edit.

Comment: If someone else accepts the edit for him, he won't be able to edit :S

Comment: That is not how editing works, @Dzyann. An author can always edit his own posts, regardless of who else has edited (or approved edits to) them.

Comment: @Shog9 I meant like the edit will get accepted and then the Author would have to create a new edit over it. I am not sure if i am mor clear now.

Comment: Not really, @Dzyann. The author can always roll back to (or edit, thus effectively rolling back to) any revision.